# How to get last value from a Subject?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have two Angular2 components which need to share data via a service:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  private searchResultSource = new Subject<string>()
  searchResult$ = this.searchResultSource.asObservable()

  setSearchResults(_searchResult: string): void {
    this.searchResultSource.next(_searchResult)
  }
}
```

Suppose `ComponentA` is rendered and it emits an event via `SearchService.setSearchResults`. Then the user navigates to `ComponentB`, which also subscribes to `searchResult$`. However, `ComponentB` will never observe the event emitted by `ComponentA` because it was not subscribed to `searchResult$` at the time `ComponentA` emitted an event, as it did not exist.

How can I create an `Observable` which emits the last event to every new subscriber?

Comment: A comprehensible and up-to-date article explaining the `AsyncSubject`, `BehaviorSubject` and `ReplaySubject` can be found here: https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

Comment: I found this to be a clear simple (no angular/TS)  explanation about the three Subjects with live code to play with https://coryrylan.com/blog/rxjs-observables-versus-subjects

Comment: Also as of rxjs 6 there is shareReply operator see comments here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730542/how-to-convert-an-observable-to-a-replaysubject-in-rxjs, docs here https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`BehaviorSubject` immediately emits the last value to new subscribers:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  private searchResultSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  setSearchResults(_searchResult: string): void {
      this.searchResultSource.next(_searchResult);
  }
}
```

`ReplaySubject` emits all previous events to new subscribers.

Comment: So the BehaviorSubject has to have an initial value always? Or maybe the initial value is not passed across subscriptions

Comment: Yes, it has to have an initial value - which could be null though.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) to always get the last value of the Observer, something like this :

```ts
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  private searchResultSource = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

  setSearchResults(_searchResult: string): void {
      this.searchResultSource.next(_searchResult);
  }
}
```

And just subscribe as normal.
A more advanced [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104277/caching-results-with-angular2-http-service/36413003#36413003) can be found here : [caching results with angular2 http service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104277/caching-results-with-angular2-http-service/36413003#36413003)

Comment: Can you explain "Subscribe as normal"? Is there any case where subscription doesnt work?

Comment: I meant that I don't need to show how you subscribe to this ReplaySubject, as you don't need to do anything special on the subscription side, just subscribe and you'll get the last value.

Comment: Okay cool. I had a situation where `BehaviorSubject` subsription didnt work but `ReplaySubject` did. Was trying to understand why.

Comment: I'm still very new to this Rx stuff and observables (aren't we all at this point?!) but this answer helped me quite a bit. For anyone in my position... I originally chose a `ReplaySubject` (opposed to `BehaviorSubject`) because you don't need to initialize a `ReplaySubject` with a value.  But subscribing to a `ReplaySubject` observable by default gives you all values that were broadcast during its lifetime. initialiazing the `ReplaySubject` with a buffer size of 1 like in @tibbus answer worked for me!