# How to convert an Observable to a ReplaySubject?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Here is what I'm doing now to convert an `Observable` to a `ReplaySubject`:

```js
const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);

observable.subscribe(e => subject.next(e));
```

Is this the best way to make the conversion, or is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: I suppose you could do `observable.subscribe(subject.next)` if you really want to shave characters. But why do you need to create the subject if you have the observable? If you just want the replay functionality, use the [`Observable.replay`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html) method.

Comment: Actually you can even do `observable.subscribe(subject)`, without the `.next`) just note that once the observable completes, so does the subject.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `Observable.replay` doesn't seem to be available in RxJS v5.

Comment: For RxJS version 6.4.0 this will do the trick: `observable.pipe(shareReplay(1))`, which is equivalent (as of 6.4.0) to `observable.pipe(shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: false }))`. For gory details on `refcount` look here: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-whats-changed-with-sharereplay-65c098843e95

Comment: docs for above shareReplay comment here https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use just `observable.subscribe(subject)` if you want to pass all 3 types of notifications because a Subject already behaves like an observer. For example:

```js
let subject = new ReplaySubject();
subject.subscribe(
    val => console.log(val),
    undefined, 
    () => console.log('completed')
);

Observable
    .interval(500)
    .take(5)
    .subscribe(subject);

setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next('Hello');
}, 1000)
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/bayewo/2/edit?js,console

However this has one important consequence. Since you've already subscribed to the source Observable you turned it from "cold" to "hot" (maybe it doesn't matter in your use-case).

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what do you mean by 'convert'.

If you need to make your observable shared and replay the values, use `observable.pipe(shareReplay(1))`.

If you want to have the subscriber functionality as well, you need to use a new ReplaySubject subscribed to the original Observable `observable.subscribe(subject);`.

Comment: Note that `shareReplay()` will not unsubscribe from the underlying observable: it will stay subscribed, and will keep the results, potentially forever. Use `shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })` whenever it makes sense to

Answer (score -1):

Like the first answer, as subject is also an observer.

```
const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
observable.subscribe(subject);
```