# Replay Subject from Observable (emit all previous events)

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have an observable and I'm trying to make a replay subject from. It should emit the current and all previous events that the observable emitted.

Here is what I thought would work, as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730542/how-to-convert-an-observable-to-a-replaysubject-in-rxjs):

```
// create an observable from dummy array and a blank replay subject
const observable$ = from([1, 2, 3])
const replay$ = new ReplaySubject()

// create a replay subject from the observable (not working as expected)
observable$.subscribe(replay$)

// log out the events
observable$.subscribe(e => console.log('observable', e) )
replay$.subscribe(e => console.log('replay', e))
```

Logs

```
observable 1
observable 2
observable 3
replay 1
replay 2
replay 3
```

The behavior I'm looking for is such that the replay subject emits the previous events as well, like so:

```
replay [1]
replay [1, 2]
replay [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I archieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReplaySubject` replays the whole sequence only on subscription. This means only when you call `replay$.subscribe()`. After that it only passes through all emissions.

From what output you want to get it looks like you want to chain it with `scan()` because `ReplaySubject` emits items one by one and not as accumulated arrays as you expect.

```
observable$.pipe(
  scan((acc, val) => [...acc, val], []),
).subscribe(replay$);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yfgkvf?file=index.ts