# How to get last emitted Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I've created an Angular service that basically sets an object with some user information. When I change the user, the service emits an observable, captured by some sibling components to update the info. The problem is that the first time I set the data, there's no one subscribed yet, so I get an undefined value. I've read about converting the observable to 'hot' using publish() or share() but I'm pretty new to RxJS and I still haven't understood how it works at 100% so I'm a little lost.

The service code (the relevant part):

```
getFwcUser() : Observable<FwcUser> {
  return this.subjectFwcUser.asObservable();
}

setFwcUser(user : FwcUser) {
  this.fwcUser = user;

  this.subjectFwcUser.next(this.fwcUser);
}
```

NOTE: FwcUser is an interface with some user fields. I run setFwcUser inside a button handler to choose the user.

The late subscriber (component code):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.fwcUserService.getFwcUser()
    .subscribe(
      (user : FwcUser) => { console.log('Received: ', user); this.fwcUser = user; }
  );
  [......]
}
```

Always prints: 'Received: undefined'.
NOTE: The component is inside an '*ngIf="fwcUser"', so it's being loaded when I call to 'setFwcUser' from a sibling component.

How could I get this component to read the last value?

Also, could someone recommend a good resource to learn about RxJS for beginners? I'm reading a couple of books on Angular4 but none of them explain it clearly...

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last value when subscribing to an Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174598/how-to-get-last-value-when-subscribing-to-an-observable)

Comment: maybe it wasn't available in rsjx<6 but there is ReplaySubject that "replays" the last emission on subscription. see https://coryrylan.com/blog/rxjs-observables-versus-subjects

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) is the answer here. Rather than a standard subject (Observable) that just emits values as they come in, a BehaviorSubject emits the last value upon `subscribe()`. You can also get the last value manually using the BehaviorSubjects `getValue()` method.

One note to make about the code below is that the `null` block in the BehaviorSubject declaration represents the initial value of the BehaviorSubject upon initialization. You could either leave it, or pre-populate it with a value.

**Service**

*EDITED: Corrected a couple of typing errors.*

```js
fwcUser: BehaviorSubject<FwcUser> = new BehaviorSubject<FwcUser>(null);
fwcUser$ = this.fwcUser.asObservable();

// Set the value of the fwcUser
updateFwcUser(user) {
    this.fwcUser.next(user);
}
```

**Component**

```js
// Subscribe to the BehaviorSubject
ngOnInit() {
    this.fwcUserService.fwcUser$.subscribe(_fwcUser => {
        this.fwcUser = _fwcUser
    }
}

// Get the current (previously emitted) value manually
getFwcUser() {
    this.fwcUser = this.fwcUserService.fwcUser.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! And how would the setFwcUser() function look like? Should it be something like this:?

`this.fwcUser = new BehaviorSubject(user);`

Comment: I updated my answer with the best way to update a BehaviorSubject. You'll want to add a function in the service that accepts the new value you want to emit and then use the `next()` function to push out the new value.

Comment: Hi again! Sorry I couldn't test it before, I've been really busy... I followed your instructions and it works perfectly! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Is there a way to use that to get the last 5 emitted, not just one?