# Create observable from object that stays alive

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, store, subscription

I'm new to RxJS. I want to create an observable of an `AppState` object that may change at any time, and subscribe to it to get those changes. This is a stripped down implementation:

```
export class AppState {

  public get observable(): Observable<any> {
     return Observable.of(this._state);
  }
}


// appState is injected into my component via angular DI

this.appState.observable
     .subscribe((appState) => {
        console.log('appState: ', appState);)
     }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
     }, () =>{
        console.log('Completed');
     });
```

But it only runs once and immediately calls `completed`. So when I change my appState, the subscription already ended.

How do I keep the subscription alive forever, like KnockOutJS style. This is used in an Angular application

UPDATE: I got it partially working with `Subject`. But the problem is now it is emitting many duplicates of the same value.

```
// full appState.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export type InternalStateType = {
   [key: string]: any
};

@Injectable()
export class AppState {

   public _state: InternalStateType = {};
   public subject: Subject<any>;

   constructor() {
      this.subject = new Subject();
   }

   /**
    * Return an observable for subscribing to.
    */
   public get observable() {
      return this.subject;
   }

   /**
    * Return a clone of the current state.
    */
   public get state() {
      this._state = this._clone(this._state);
      this.subject.next(this._state);
      return this._state;
   }

   /**
    * Never allow mutation
    */
   public set state(value) {
      throw new Error('do not mutate the `.state` directly');
   }

   public get(prop?: any) {
      /**
       * Use our state getter for the clone.
       */
      const state = this.state;
      return state.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? state[prop] : state;
   }

   public set(prop: string, value: any) {
      /**
       * Internally mutate our state.
       */
      return this._state[prop] = value;
   }

   private _clone(object: InternalStateType) {
      /**
       * Simple object clone.
       */
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
   }
}
```

What needs to be changed to get it to only emit the change once for each change to `this._state`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md), or a [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md).

A Subject will emit values to subscribers as they are passed to the Subject, while a BehaviorSubject will emit the last value given upon subscription and then continue to emit values as they become available.

Comment: Thanks, can give you a basic example of how its used? I'm reading through the docs but example will help. Their example isn't making sense as I try to apply it to my object

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302999/how-to-get-last-emitted-observable/46303105#46303105) is another question I answered that is very similar. It provides a pretty good example of basic `BehvaiorSubject` usage.

Comment: Thank you @joshrathke - you answer in that other question with example code gave me the info I needed to get it working.