# Get Last Value from Observable in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular8

How do I get the last value from an Observable in Angular 8?

```
let test = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
test.next(this.AddressObservable);

let lastValue = test.subscribe(data=>console.log(data.value));
```

For some reason it is not working, checking debugger.

However, this is working in html, `AddressObservable | async`

Trying to utilize this link, want to store value in variable or display in console log. Any newer syntax would be helpful .

[How to get last value when subscribing to an Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174598/how-to-get-last-value-when-subscribing-to-an-observable)

**Note:**

`AddressObservable` is of type: `Observable<AddressDto>`

Comment: Your code looks a little confusing. You are initializing a behavior subject with a string, and then emitting another observable through the subject. Can you post the relevant code to give this post context

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Judging by the question, there seems to be confusion with the `BehaviorSubject` and what it does.

A `Subject` is effectively a stream of values from some source that you can subscribe to. Whenever a new value is emitted, it arrives in the `subscribe` method.

If you have an initial state, you can use a `BehaviorSubject` to initialise the subject and ensure new subscribers always receive a value.

If you don't have an initial state, but want to ensure new subscribers get the last emitted value on subscribing—if one exists—then you can use `ReplaySubject`.

All of the values that go into a `Subject` are of type T, where you have `Subject<T>`. Therefore, in your case, everything going into the `Subject` should be an `AddressDto`.

If you have an initial address, then you would set up your `BehaviorSubject` as follows.

```
// Somehow get the initial address.
const address = new AddressDto();
const test = new BehaviorSubject<AddressDto>(address);

// All subscribers will receive this address on subscribing.

// Something happens.

// There is another address; emit that.
const newAddress = new AddressDto();
test.next(newAddress);

// All new subscribers will receive newAddress on subscribing.
```

On the other hand, if you don't have an initial address you can use a `ReplaySubject` as demonstrated below.

```
// Always emit the last address to new subscribers by intitialising it with the number 1.

// New subscribers won't receive an address until one is emitted.
const test = new ReplaySubject<AddressDto>(1);

// Something happens.

// Get the first address, and emit it.
const firstAddress = new AddressDto();
test.next(firstAddress);

// All current subscribers receive firstAddress.

// All future subscribers will receive firstAddress on subscribing

// Something happens.

const secondAddress = new AddressDto();
test.next(secondAddress);

// All current subscribers receive secondAddress.

// All future subscribers will receive secondAddress on subscribing.
```

### Edit

You asked about storing the last value in a variable, which is ambiguous. I'm going to assume you mean at the source as that's more complex.

Once you get your head around the concept of `Subject` and `Observable`, you might understand the idea of the `Observable` `Pipe`. All sorts of stuff can happen inside a `Pipe`; think of it as a series of steps of things that can happen to an object. It is similar to a series of chained array functions on a normal array in JavaScript.

One of the things you can do in a `Pipe` is to perform "side effects" in a `Tap` operator. This means that you can do stuff in the middle of a `Pipe` while letting the data pass through it. To give two examples, you could store the value in a variable, or in `localStorage`.

If you have control of what's going in the `Subject`, it seems redundant to do this in a `Pipe`; therefore, the following example shows how to cache the result of an HTTP request.

```
this.http.get(url).pipe(
  // Transform the HTTP response into an object that is created.
  map(response => this.mapResponseToMyClass(response)),
  // Store the mapped object in a local property for later use.
  tap(myClass => {
    // Perform any 'side effect' actions you want, such as the below.
    console.log(myClass);
    // Store the value in a variable.
    this.cachedMyClass = myClass;
  })
);
```

'Piping' your own `Subject` is no different. Everything that goes into a `Subject` will go through a `Pipe` and is then outputted to the subscriber.

```
private subject = new Subject<AddressDto>();

getPostcode(): Observable<string> {
  // Reuse the local Subject. All subscribers to this function will receive addresses that have come through the Pipe.
  return subject.pipe(
    map(address => address.postcode),
    // Store the last postcode in a local property.
    tap(postcode => this.lastPostcode = postcode)
    // The postcode is outputted here to all subscribers
  ).asObservable();
}
```

Comment: ok, How do I store the value of the last dto in a variable after doing next? or display in console log?  trying to setup subscription properly, thanks

Comment: also don't see the subjects linking to AddressObservable above

Comment: need linkage to observable and subscription example would be helpful

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, so I've added an example of how you can log to the console and store to a local variable. There are many better tutorials on using observables and pipes than this, but I appreciate it can all be a bit overwhelming to start with

Comment: This is such a helpful answer - ty

Answer (score 1):

Observable does not store value. You should have subscribed to Observable before you have push data in Observable stream to receive value. I think Your AddressObservable is an Observable, not BehaviorSubject. If you convert AddressObservable to BehaviorSubject. It will work. In case AsyncPipe it is working because it async pipe subscribe for the same.

Change AddressObservable to type: BehaviorSubject