# Caching http get response for performance reasons with Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

The potential 'duplicate' questions do not answer my question - I potentially think my use of Observables is different than the examples and as I point out, I attempted using share() unsuccessfully.

I have a service which looks like that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Card } from '../../card';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CardService {
    private privateUrl = 'http://localhost:3335/cardname/';
    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    public getDetailedInfo(card): Observable<Card> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.privateUrl}${card.name}`)
            .map(this.extractData);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return new Card(body.data.name, body.data.card_type, body.data.text);
    }
}
```

And a component that uses it that looks like :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Card } from '../../card';
import { CardService } from '../../services/card/card.service';
import { CARDNAMES } from '../../cards';

@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    styles: [require('./main.component.scss').toString()],
    template: require('./main.component.html'),
    providers: [CardService]
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    mode = 'Observable';
    title = 'YuGiOh Deck Browser';
    cardnames = CARDNAMES;
    card: Card;
    selectedCard: Card;
    dataStore: Array<any> = [];

    constructor(private cardService: CardService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        for (let prop in this.cardnames) {
            this.getDetailedInfo(this.cardnames[prop]);
        }
    }

    onSelect(card: Card): void {
        this.getDetailedInfo(card);
    }

    getDetailedInfo(card) {
        this.cardService.getDetailedInfo(card)
            .subscribe((card: Card) => {
                this.card = this.selectedCard = card;
                this.dataStore.push(card);
            });
    }
}
```

My template is:

```
<div *ngIf="card">
    <h2>{{card.name}}</h2>
    <div class="card-type">{{card?.card_type}}</div>
    <div class="card-description">{{card?.text}}</div>
</div>
```

and my Card looks like that:

```
export class Card {
    response:string;
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public card_type: string,
        public text: string
    ) { }
}
```

I tried using `share()`, `cache()`, `publishReplay(1).refCount()` after reading [this](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0) and [that](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/share.html) but nothing seems stop that HTTP Get request to be called when the click handler is called.

Am I misunderstanding what these methods actually do?

I also made an attempt, following [this first answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in) to save my data in an array of objects in memory (code sample following) which partially works, but fails when I click and trigger the onSelect event.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Card } from '../../card';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CardService {
    private dataStore: Array<any> = [];
    private observable: Observable<Card>;
    private privateUrl = 'http://localhost:3335/cardname/';
    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    public getDetailedInfo(card): Observable<any> {
        if (this.dataStore.length > 0) {
            this.dataStore.forEach((value, index) => {
                return new Card(
                    this.dataStore[index].data.name,
                    this.dataStore[index].data.card_type,
                    this.dataStore[index].data.text
                )
            });
        } else if (this.observable) {
            return this.observable;
        } else {
            return this.http.get(`${this.privateUrl}${card.name}`)
                .map(
                    (res) => {
                        let body = res.json();
                        this.dataStore.push(body);
                        return new Card(body.data.name, body.data.card_type, body.data.text);
                    }
                );
        }
    }
}

    VM99537:93 EXCEPTION: Error in ./MainComponent class MainComponent - inline template:4:8

2016-09-11 21:04:03.241 zone.js?c625:269 Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in ./MainComponent class MainComponent - inline template:4:8

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at MainComponent.getDetailedInfo (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/bundle.js:965:2), <anonymous>:32:13)
    at MainComponent.onSelect (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/bundle.js:965:2), <anonymous>:27:14)
    at DebugAppView._View_MainComponent1._handle_click_0_0 (MainComponent.ngfactory.js:172:35)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/common.js:1731:2), <anonymous>:381:24)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/common.js:2322:2), <anonymous>:255:36)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/common.js:2364:2), <anonymous>:27:111)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/vendor.js:472:2), <anonymous>:332:29)
    at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/common.js:1551:2), <anonymous>:53:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/vendor.js:472:2), <anonymous>:331:35)
    at Zone.runGuarded (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/vendor.js:472:2), <anonymous>:239:48)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in

Comment: Can anyone explain: George's code never calls `subscribe()`, so I don't understand why the Observable chain (the HTTP request) even gets triggered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [caching results with angular2 http service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104277/caching-results-with-angular2-http-service)

Comment: @cartant I've obviously read this question and have made attempts to use share() unsuccesfully - therefore this is no duplicate as my code is quite different than the questions.

Comment: @BeetleJuice interesting.. I just placed a debugger in the callback of subscribe and I can safely say it's called..

Answer (score 0):

Your data store is a good idea, but I see a couple of problems with your implementation. The biggest is that when the component calls `Service.getDetaileInfo`, it expects an `Observable<Card>` but this fails in two instance from your code:

```
//this returns a Card instead of an Observable<Card>
if (this.dataStore.length > 0)... return New Card

//this never seems to be true since you never assign anything to this.observable
else if (this.observable) return this.observable
```

My service would look something like:

```
//object that holds cards already fetched from server
private cache = {};
private url = '...';

/** takes Card.name and returns Observable that emits detailed info
    from the cache if possible, from the server if not */
public getDetailedInfo(name):Observable<Card> {

   // if a Card by that name is in the cache, return it as an Observable
   if (this.cache[name]) return Observable.of(this.cache[name]);

   //call the server and convert results to JS object and access .data
   return this.http.get('...').map( res => res.json().data)

               // transform object to a new Card
              .map(data => new Card(data.name, data.card_type, data.text))

              // store result in the cache, under the card's name
              .do(card => this.cache[card.name] = card)
}
```

In the component, you can just call `Service.getDetailedInfo()` when you need the details. The component doesn't need its own datastore.

Comment: `this.cache.name` : cache doesn't have a name property up there.. (compiler is complaining) 
in general somethings wrong with cache = {}

Comment: this code doesn't run :( too many errors during compilation from TS

Comment: `(18,20): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Card>'.`

Comment: what is lowercase card ? 
'card' ? for example `.do(card => this.cache[card.name] = card)` where do you get card from?

Comment: The `.do()` is the next callback in an observable stream, so its input (I named it `card`, but I could have used `foo`) is the output of the previous callback. So `card` is the `new Card` that `.map()` just above it returned

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos In response to *"this.cache.name: cache doesn't have a name property"*: you make a good point. I have fixed the `if(this.cache.name)...` line above to use `if(this.cache[name])...` instead. the idea is to check whether there is a property whose name matches the card's name. My mistake was to look for a property named `name`.

Comment: `.do(card => this.cache[card.name] = card)` : `error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'void'`.

Comment: alright, I got it to work using your code :) can we go into chat mode for one - two quick questions ? :)

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Assuming you used the code in my answer, the argument `card` in `.do()` is the `new Card()`  that the previous function returned:   This is something you have control over, so if it's of type `void`, something may be wrong with either the `Card` constructor, or the data the server returned and that is used to call `new Card()`

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos sorry I'm in the middle of something.