# How to reuse service calls in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two components using the same service. On `FirstComponent`, I get some data from a service:

```
getLiveData() {
  Observable.interval(1000)
    .mergeMap(() => this.service.getData())
    .subscribe(
      res => this.data = res,
      err => this.error = err
    );
}
```

At first, I've added another `getLiveData()` to the `SecondComponent`. However, that way I'm making two REST calls every second. That shouldn't  be needed as I want to use the same service.

So, can I reuse that in the `SecondComponent` without making two calls every time?

I tried to add the `FirstComponent` as a service and called `this.service.data` but I'm getting `undefined`.

PS. I also need the values to be updated every second on both components.

**UPDATE:** *I've posted a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lTnKkqn7VMTflQE09kOL?p=preview) following Madhu's advice. I managed to get only one call per time, but I'm not getting any data from it.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in

Comment: Please check the answers on this question. I think this might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104277/caching-results-with-angular2-http-service

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It didn't work for me. When I use `Observable.interval`, it keeps calling the service twice. :/

Comment: Hard to know what exactly you're doing.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I guess your method only calls the data again if it's not in the cache, right? For my case, I need it to make a call to the network every 1s. Using your method, it calls the network only when the app starts: http://plnkr.co/edit/F3E8uPnhXM08ptf6iGNz?p=preview - after that, it calls every 1s but only the cache data.

Comment: You can clear the cache every second, then it calls to the server again if it can't find the data in the cache.

Comment: I'm not sure that would solve the problem. In the Plunker above, the `getData()` is called twice every time. So, it would probably make two network requests as well, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below,

```
@Injectable()
export class MyAwesomeService{
  _streamingData: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  streamingObservable = {};

  get streamingData$(){
    return this._streamingData.asObservable();
  }      

  getLiveData(){
    if(!!this.streamingObservable){
    const start = 10;
    this.streamingObservable =  Observable
         .interval(1000)
         .mergeMap(() => this.service.getData())
         .subscribe(
            res => {
              this._streamingData.next(res);
            },
            err => {
              console.log(err);
            }
         );
    }
    return this.streamingObservable;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3>Live streaming data</h3>
   <hr />
   <child-comp-1></child-comp-1>
   <hr />
   <child-comp-2></child-comp-2>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { }

@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp-1',
  template: `<h3>Child component</h3>
   Streaming Data: {{ data | async }}
  `
})
export class ChildComponent1 {
  data = "Hello!!";
  constructor(private myservice:MyAwesomeService){
    this.data= myservice.streamingData$;
    myservice.getLiveData();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp-2',
  template: `<h3>Child component 2</h3>
   Streaming Data: {{ data | async }}
  `
})
export class ChildComponent2 {
  data = "Hello!!";
  constructor(private myservice:MyAwesomeService){
    this.data= myservice.streamingData$;
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xe9W3CWLpyRCZHIcNjr3?p=preview), In Plunk i have simulated service data with a simple map which gives data at an interval.

**Update**

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I9ewCITuVZTvRLTuz6LN?p=preview)** with consuming API using Http.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, @MandhurRanjan. Do you know how I can use that with an `HTTP` call? If I try to `map` the `URL` I get an error: `argument is not a function. Are you looking for mapTo()?`: http://plnkr.co/edit/0fl79aTUBMgwk00ujgJy?p=preview

Comment: I managed to get only one call per time, but I'm not getting any data from it. I've updated the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lTnKkqn7VMTflQE09kOL?p=preview

Comment: Check out this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I9ewCITuVZTvRLTuz6LN?p=preview), Cheers!!

Comment: @drbishop:  Note in one component i have added a json pipe so that you may see json  response.

Comment: Thanks, @MadhuRanjan! I own you a beer! =) btw, I didn't know that `jsonplaceholder` website. It's very useful to try out those things.

Comment: Glad I could be of help!!

Comment: One more thing: do you know why I'm not able to retrieve the values inside the `json` (i.e. `{{data.id}}`)? http://plnkr.co/edit/AuGDmHkfVv0ZD9AOCjCN?p=preview

Comment: check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hfPQVtH2WPk8Cc9z5Sl9?p=preview)!!

Comment: Oh, I was forgetting to subscribe haha. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to move the interval to the service.

```
observableSub;
getDataObservable() {
    if (!this.observableSub) {
        this.observableSub = Observable.interval(1000)
            .mergeMap(() => this.getData())
    } 
    return this.observableSub;
}
```

And on the component:

```
getLiveData() {
  this.getDataObservable().subscribe(
      res => this.data = res,
      err => this.error = err
    );
}
```